# How to add write review link on product list page.if there is no any review of same product product

Tags: magento

I want to add a link to the 'write review' page on the category page, in case there is no review of the same product. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can count the amount of reviews of a product as follows:

```
$reviewCount = $_product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount() ? $_product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount(): 0;
if($reviewCount == 0){
    //add write review link here 
}
```

And write the anchor tag as follows:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('review/product/list', array('id'=> $_product->getId())); ?>#review-form" rel="nofollow"> <?php echo $this->__('Write Review') ?></a>
```

Comment: yes but i want to add 'write review' url on product listing page
i used  <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form" rel="nofollow"> <?php echo $this->__('Write Review') ?></a>

but it is not working........:(

Comment: Try `Mage::getUrl('review/product/list', array('id'=> $_product->getId()))`;

Comment: Instead of `$this->getReviewsUrl()` you can write code as per above comment